# Angular8 create dynamic container that other modules can inject their components

Tags: angular, angular8

I was wondering if it is possible to create a `space` in angular8 that can act as dynamic container.

Closest example would be left panel ads container.

[image]

Is it possible to create such thing in angular8? So that other modules can inject components there by themselves without modifying `LayoutModule`?

Comment: Did you check [**this**](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)?

Comment: Why dont you use the ng-template angular element? https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template

Comment: It is not a problem of dynamically injecting components. Problem is dynamically injecting components by **other modules**, without touching Layout module

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

You should read more about `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

Since the code to achieve this is too complicated to post here, I’ll link you to an article describing the technique.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Comment: That completely doesn't solve my problem. The "without modifying LayoutModule" is the key here.